# Does get.edgelist in R library igraph return proper directed edges?

Tags: r, igraph

If the graph passed to get.edgelist is directed, does the list of edges as returned by get.edgelist maintain the proper directions? I would think that this is the case but the [documentation found here](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/conversion.html) doesn't seem to say anything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. Being one of the igraph authors, I know that this is surely the case. :) We will fix the documentation in the next release.